# Python Flask-SQLAlchemy inheritance

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make an insert query but I'm getting this error:

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: Attempting to flush an item of type
>    as a member of collection "Tag.item". Expected
>   an object of type  or a polymorphic subclass of
>   this type. If  is a subclass of , configure mapper "Mapper|Item|items" to load this
>   subtype polymorphically, or set enable_typechecks=False to allow any
>   subtype to be accepted for flush.

The insert query

```
        project = Proyecto.query.filter_by(id_project=id_project).first()
        creado_en = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        nuevo_hub = Hub(name,location,comments,creado_en)
        #FAIL HERE, even if Hub extends of Item
        nuevo_tag = Tag(project,nuevo_hub,TYPE_HUB,creado_en)
        db.session.add(nuevo_tag)
        db.session.add(nuevo_hub)
        db.session.commit()
```

The rest of code

```
class Item(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "items"
    id_item     = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    type        = db.Column(db.Integer)
    created_at  = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    updated_at  = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'items',
        'polymorphic_on':type,
        'with_polymorphic':'*'
    }

    def __init__(self,creado_en=None):
        self.created_at = creado_en
        self.updated_at = creado_en



class Hub(Item):
    __tablename__ = "hubs"
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 0,
        'with_polymorphic':'*'
    }
    id_hub = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('items.id_item'), primary_key=True)
    # id_hub = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, index= True)
    location = db.Column(db.String(50))
    comments = db.Column(db.String(128))
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    # conexiones = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, nombre=None, location=None,comments=None, creado_en=None):
        self.name = nombre
        self.location = location
        self.comments = comments
        self.created_at = creado_en
        self.updated_at = creado_en



class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tags"
    id_tag      = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    id_project  = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("projects.id_project"))
    id_item     = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("items.id_item"))
    project     = db.relationship(Proyecto, backref=db.backref('list_tags', lazy='dynamic'))
    item        = db.relationship(Item, backref=db.backref('list_tags', lazy='dynamic'))
    type        = db.Column(db.Integer) #(0,hub);(1,cable);(2,pipe);(3,electrical_pipes)
    created_at  = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    updated_at  = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __init__(self,project,item,type,created_at):
        self.project = project
        self.item = item
        self.type = type
        self.created_at = created_at
        self.updated_at = created_at
```

Comment: What type of inheritance are you doing? You don't have `polymorphic_on` or `concrete` in your mapper args.

Comment: @univerio I have updated the code to use polymorphic_on

Comment: Now everything is working fine!!

Comment: @Ricardo If you figured it out, can you please answer your own question with an explanation and code sample?

Comment: Hi @Ricardo, I'm facing same the same error today, how do you figure out it..?
Please answer it in your own question :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case I fix that based on this answer:
[Flask-SQLAlchemy polymorphic association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000045/flask-sqlalchemy-polymorphic-association)

Also, the [official SQLAlchemy](https://docs-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/ko/latest/orm/inheritance.html) docs can help:

> Joined Table Inheritance In joined table inheritance, each class along
> a particular classes’ list of parents is represented by a unique
> table. The total set of attributes for a particular instance is
> represented as a join along all tables in its inheritance path. Here,
> we first define the Employee class. This table will contain a primary
> key column (or columns), and a column for each attribute that’s
> represented by Employee. In this case it’s just name:
>
> ```py
> class Employee(Base):
>     __tablename__ = 'employee'
>     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
>     name = Column(String(50))
>     type = Column(String(50))
>
>     __mapper_args__ = {
>         'polymorphic_identity':'employee',
>         'polymorphic_on':type
>     }
> ```

I think your code should look like:

```py
class Hub(Item):
    __tablename__ = "hubs"
    
    id_hub = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, index= True)
    location = db.Column(db.String(50))
    comments = db.Column(db.String(128))
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    # conexiones = db.Column(db.Integer)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 0,
        'polymorphic_on': id_hub
    }

    def __init__(self, nombre=None, location=None,comments=None, creado_en=None):
        self.name = nombre
        self.location = location
        self.comments = comments
        self.created_at = creado_en
        self.updated_at = creado_en
```

You may also need to set is to `concrete = True` to be able to query it from child class.

*Concrete inheritance is inheritance of **method** implementations and member variables **from a super-class**.*

Details at:
[Abstract Concrete Classes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/inheritance.html#abstract-concrete-classes)

```
__mapper_args__ = {
    'polymorphic_identity': 0,
    'polymorphic_on': id_hub,
    'concrete': True
}
```